# Cannot remove a user from ms teams public channel

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have a teams account which has different channels like Marketing, Sales etc. But every member on teams is part of all public channels there is no option  to remove members from public channel. Is this is the default behaviour of teams I mean we can't remove a member from public channel?

Comment: It would be better to ask this on Superuser instead of Stack Overflow since this question is not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's correct, and the terminology makes sense in that regard - you're adding the person to the "Team", and that means *all* public content for that Team (channels, docs, etc.). If this is a problem, you'd need to use private channels, or separate Teams, or similar. Recall though that users can show/hide channels in the left menu, and you can "tag" users to target communications at them, as some examples of ways to help.